# Book about a soldier in powered armour fighting aliens near the pyramids at Giza

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I read this book a while ago in school (early 2000's I think) but I cannot find it again as I have forgotten the title. I will summarize it as well as I can from my memory of it:

- Main character is a male
- He is part of a unit (possibly military?) that has powered armour. The armour completely covers them and is solid black. Think there were lights on the shoulder as well as interchangeable weapons on the arms. Kind of like the Halo Mjolnir armour but is more form fitting and smooth on the outside, and solid black coloured.
- There is a manual release inside the helmet that opens it up when the batteries are damaged/depleted that is worked by the person's tongue. This is the part I remember the most because the main character has to use this release after he gets attacked while in one of the pyramids of Giza. He starts to panic when he realizes that the suit has no power but then he remembers about the manual release and he has to feel around and find the release with his tongue.
- The antagonists are aliens and a portion of the book takes place in a pyramid of Giza.

  - Somewhere in the book they go to the source of the Nile river by going submerged in their powered armour. The source of the Nile was either the pyramids at Giza or was otherwise a major factor in the plot.
- There may have been a portion of the book where combat took place in space in their armour suits but I might be completely wrong about this.

I have tried to find this book many other times through Google but all the keywords I can remember are pretty generic and shared between a LOT of books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some creative keyword searching in Google I figured out that the book(s) I'm looking for are the "Area 51" series by Bob Mayer/Robert Doherty. The book I was thinking about was specifically "Area 51: The Sphinx" (http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/360927.The_Sphinx) but I'm now reading the whole series.

> It could be "Star Corp" first book of the Legacy Trilogy by Ian Douglas: >http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_Trilogy

Thanks Jim2B, not the book I was looking for but a new one to add to my to-read list :-)

Comment: I know, right?!

My favorite part of this website is reading interesting descriptions and finding new books to read.

It almost makes me want to post interesting descriptions of books I really loved and then answering them so others learn about them.

Answer (score 3):

It could be "Star Corp" first book of the Legacy Trilogy by Ian Douglas: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_Trilogy

Some aspects of my answer match your description while other parts do not.

"Star Corp" starts with combat near and on the Pyramids.  The marines have combat armor but I don't remember whether it is powered or not at this point in the story.  In this first battle scene at the Pyramids the enemy is actually other humans but later in the book they fight aliens (but in other locations).

The Legacy Trilogy books don't really have a single protagonist but instead jump around to give the perspective of many different people in the unit.

I don't recall them needing to find or go to the source of the Nile.